# How to Exit iOS Recovery Mode

Tags: ios

My iOS device is stuck in Recovery Mode.

[image]

How do I exit this mode?

Comment: I've edited the question to make it far less localized so future users suffering from this problem can find help. The answer is below.

Comment: Google my friend could have been a great source. Anyway, welcome to Apple.StackExchange

Answer (score 2):

## iOS 7

1. Hold down the home button and the lock button at the same time.
2. Keep holding them down until you see the Apple logo then release the
   buttons and you should be finished!

Source: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oX9VM590pvo

## iOS 6

1. Download the [TinyUmbrella](http://blog.firmwareumbrella.com) application.
2. Connect your iPhone or iPod in Recovery mode to your Mac or PC using its USB cable.
3. Open TinyUmbrella and give it a few seconds until it recognizes your device.

[image]

Source: http://www.guidingtech.com/16182/get-iphone-out-of-recovery-mode/

Comment: From tinyUmbrella-site: In order for the ‘Fix Recovery’ button to be enabled you must put your device in DFU.

Answer (score 1):

Try holding down the power and the home button until the screen turns white, then let go and it should reboot

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the device is NOT connected anywhere via a USB cable
2. Hold down the Home button and the Power button at the same time for 10 seconds. (or until you see your iDevice booting up regularly).

If that does not help, make sure to leave your iDevice to charge for at least an hour and try the above procedure again.